# ODAC при запросе подменяет * на view.*

Tags: sql, oracle, .net, odac

Приложение на .NET с использованием `Oracle.DataAccess` обращается к БД и делает запрос. Так я пишу в коде:

```
SELECT * FROM SHEMA.VIEW
```

, где `SHEMA.VIEW` - представление.

При этом, администратор БД видит запрос так:

```
SELECT SHEMA.VIEW.* FROM SHEMA.VIEW
```

Вопрос скорее принципиальный - почему так? Почему они различаются и что за этим стоит?

---

PS администраторы БД в логах хотят видеть запросы в том виде, в каком их задают в ПО. Считают (и правильно), что незнание таких скрытых механизмов снижают доверие к разработчику и к разрабатываемому им ПО.

Comment: `SHEMA.VIEW.*` это полное квалифицированное имя. Чем оно вам не подходит или не нравится?

Comment: @0xdb администраторы БД в логах хотят видеть запросы в том виде, в каком их задают в ПО. Считают (и правильно), что незнание таких скрытых механизмов снижают доверие к разработчику и к разрабатываемому им ПО
сам вопрос решили, изменив запрос на

  SELECT t.* FROM SHEMA.VIEW t
так подмены не происходит

Comment: @0xdb попробую пояснить. Первый вид - это строка, которую я пишу в коде. Второй - так запрос видит администратор в БД. Вопрос в том почему они различаются и что за этим стоит

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому, что слой приложения, который отвечает за обмен данными с БД, может изменить, и обычно меняет запрос, до его отправки на сервер БД. Тем самым пытаясь, например, улучшить производительность запроса, или привести запрос в соответствие с особенностями конкретного бренда БД.

Так синтаксически правильно:

```sql
select * from view1;
```

А так тоже правильно, но более правильно:

```sql
select me.t.* from view1 t;
```

С указанием полного квалифицированного имени обьекта БД ([FQN - fully qualified name](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Syntax-for-Schema-Objects-and-Parts-in-SQL-Statements.html#GUID-08B73ED6-2ABA-4737-B8A1-F7BD0456AEDB)) не будет производится поиск идентификаторов в пространстве имён.

---

> администраторы БД в логах хотят видеть запросы в том виде, в каком их задают в ПО

Но их желание необоснованно. Первый запрос более удобочитаем, чем второй:

```sql
select id from someTable;

select someSchemaOfSalesDepartment.someTable.id from someTable;
```

Разработчик в первую очередь должен заботится, чтобы запрос был понятным и удобочитаемым, а не как он будет выглядеть на стороне сервера БД.